# HTML-CSS table troubleshoot

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<table>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>SUN</th>
<th>MON</th>
<th>TUE</th>
<th>WED</th>
<th>THU</th>
<th>FRI</th>
<th>SAT</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Morning<br>7AM-12PM</td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Afternoon<br>12PM-5PM</td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Evening<br>5PM-9PM</td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
<td><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked"><label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the css is

```
table, tr, th, td 
{
//border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}
table 
{
border-spacing: 15px;
}
td .dar, .dark
{
background-color: #888;
}
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 1.2em;
  height           : 1.2em;
   margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(192,192,192);
  border-radius    : 0.70em;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}


input[type=radio]:not(old):checked +  label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : .82em;
  height           : .82em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 0.70em;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
```

I am not able to do 2 things:

1. Set all radio buttons inside a box which has a border that differentiates them from "Days" above and "Time" from the left.
2. Set the background color as grey for the entire division that appears below "SUN" and "SAT"

Thank you in advance. I very well appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like its a common table style so i cleaned up and annotated my code a bit in case it helps others in the future.

css added

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 0;
}

tr td:nth-child(2), tr td:nth-child(8)  {
    background-color: grey;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(n+2) { border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px; }

tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(n+2) { border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; }

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) { border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; }

tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) { border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px; }

tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2) { border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px; }

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(8) { border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px; }

tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(8) { border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px; }

tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(8) { border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px; }
```

html unchanged

annotations in the fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/uw1d4cLr/2/

alternative days-as-rows fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/3hjqcamv/2/

Comment: Is there a way to make same changes to this one? I would really appreciate your help..

Comment: Same changes like the previous one in "SUN" and "SAT"

Comment: Yes Brother.. Anyways, you guys are awesome!

Comment: Just need to remove the color #FAFAFA from "SUN" and "SAT" now. And to be honest, I am a newbie in HTML-CSS and I am trying to improve my skills.

Comment: Perfect! Cheerio! You are one hell of a designer!

Comment: i'm pretty amateur but glad to help. if youre working a lot with tables check out how to alternate the background colours of rows and columns with even and odd selection.. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html  you can use the same background colour and just adjust the opacity with rgba, ex. rgba(0,0,0,0.5) and rgba(0,0,0,0.9)

Comment: I always refer that site. Also Sir, I tried updating the changes to remove color #FAFAFA from "SUN" and "SAT" in this fddle. But, didn't get any success. Do you have any idea on how I can remove the color #FAFAFA from "SUN" and "SAT" in this exisiting fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/3hjqcamv/1/

Comment: I want "SUN" and "SAT" to be normal and not inherit the color #FAFAFA from its row fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/3hjqcamv/3/

Comment: the color #FAFAFA is at the very last line is css file in the mentioned fiddle

Comment: i understand now, i think. you needed to add a td:nth-chil;d(n+2) which means starts at the 2nd column and everything after https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/3hjqcamv/4/ (change color back to FAFAFA)

Comment: Yes, that one helped. Thank you again.

Comment: in tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(n+2).. tr:nth-child(2) selects 2nd row ..and.. td:nth-child(n+2) selects the cells of the 2nd column and all cells/columns after, in the second row. so row 2 columns 2-4, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For borders :

```
table tr td:first-child { border:1px solid black; border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px; }
th:not(:first-child) { border:1px solid black; border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px; }
```

For grey bg color

```
table tr td:nth-child(2), table tr td:nth-child(8) { background-color:grey; }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baez2q4a/)

Comment: looks like i was too slow :D here's another fiddle (needs lots of cleaning up/simplifying).. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/uw1d4cLr/